# Woocommerce - Add description to category thumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have my shop set up as follows:

Shop page > Category > Subcategory > Product

The shop page shows a list of categories in a grid format, with a title and thumbnail for each category.

The Category page shows a list of categories in a grid format, with a title and thumbnail for each category.

I would like each of these grid items to also show the category description.

This is where I've got to so far (functions.php), which outputs the static text in the correct place. I can't figure out how to call the dynamic category description where the static text currently outputs.

```
function my_theme_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description() {
    echo '<div class="term-description">' . 'Code to show description here please' . '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'my_theme_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description');
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you please try this

```
function my_theme_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description($category) {
    $category_id = $category->term_id;
    echo '<div class="term-description">' . category_description( $category_id ). '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'my_theme_woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description');
```

OR else try this one

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title','custom_add_product_description', 12);
function custom_add_product_description ($category) {
  $cat_id        =    $category->term_id;
  $prod_term    =    get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
  $description=    $prod_term->description;

  echo '<div class="term-description">'.$description.'</div>';
}
```

Try this one

```
function addcatagorydescription( $category ) {
   echo '<div class="term-description">' . $category->description . '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'addcatagorydescription', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Neither of those functions did anything unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share the category page link here

Comment: It is not on a live environment yet - only my local. I know that probably doesn't help, but it is unmodified woocommerce. The file is this: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product_cat.php

Comment: As per your question the static text is displayed in the correct place, so you just use the parameter of $category in function. And inside the function just use print_r($category); and share the output.

Comment: PHP warning: 'Notice: Undefined variable: category'

Answer (score 2):

I was able to display the category description with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'custom_add_product_description', 12);
function custom_add_product_description ($category) {
    $cat_id =    $category->term_id;
    $prod_term =    get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
    $description =    $prod_term->description;

    echo '<div class="term-description">' .$description. '</div>';
}
```